# newcommand with optional argument displays wrong text

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, listings, labels

I tried to set up a new command with optional arguments. The problem is that the command displays 'st:code'. What's wrong?
Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    escapechar = §
}

\newcommand{\lstref}[2][\empty]{
    \ifdefequal{#1}{\empty}
  {Listing \ref{#1}}        
  {Zeile \ref{#2} in Listing \ref{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:code}]
some code §\label{ln:code}§
\end{lstlisting}

Text Text \lstref{lst:code}(works) Text Text \lstref[lst:code]{ln:code}(prints st:code)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test `\ifdefequal` is wrong.

You're better using `xparse` that allows to better distinguish when an optional argument is present or not.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  escapechar = §,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lstref}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {Listing \ref{#2}}
    {Zeile \ref{#2} in Listing \ref{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Whatever,label={lst:code}]
some code §\label{ln:code}§
\end{lstlisting}

Reference to the listing only: \lstref{lst:code}

Reference to the line number: \lstref[lst:code]{ln:code}
\end{document}
```

Of course you need to specify the caption in the listing, if you want the number to appear.

[image]

A better test with `etoolbox` would be

```
\newcommand{\lstref}[2][]{%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {Listing \ref{#2}}
    {Zeile \ref{#2} in Listing \ref{#1}}%
}
```